# Fold method using List as accumulator

Tags: scala

To find prime factors of a number I was using this piece of code :

```
 def primeFactors(num: Long): List[Long] = {
   val exists = (2L to math.sqrt(num).toLong).find(num % _ == 0)
    exists match {
     case Some(d) => d :: primeFactors(num/d)
     case None => List(num)
  }
}
```

but this I found a cool and more functional approach to solve this using this code:

```
def factors(n: Long): List[Long] = (2 to math.sqrt(n).toInt)
.find(n % _ == 0).fold(List(n)) ( i => i.toLong :: factors(n / i))
```

Earlier I was using `foldLeft` or `fold` simply to get sum of a list or other simple calculations, but here I can't seem to understand how fold is working and how this is breaking out of the recursive function.Can somebody plz explain how fold functionality is working here.

Answer (score 4):

**Option's `fold`**

If you look at the signature of [Option](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.Option)'s `fold` function, it takes two parameters:

```
def fold[B](ifEmpty: => B)(f: A => B): B
```

What it does is, it applies `f` on the value of `Option` if it is not empty. If `Option` is empty, it simply returns output of `ifEmpty` (this is termination condition for recursion).

So in your case, `i => i.toLong :: factors(n / i)` represents `f` which will be evaluated if `Option` is not empty. While `List(n)` is termination condition.

**`fold` used for collection / iterators**

The other `fold` that you are taking about for getting sum of collection, comes from [TraversableOnce](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.collection.TraversableOnce) and it has signature like:

```
def foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) => B): B
```

Here, `z` is starting value (suppose incase of sum it's `0`) and `op` is associative binary operator which is applied on `z` and each value of collection from left to right.

So both `fold`s differ in their implementation.

Comment: thanks @Sudhir Singh, it helped, but how its appending to List(n), can u explain that a bit..

Comment: I was mixed up b/w folds, thought there is only collection fold used

Comment: A "predicate" is a function that yields a Boolean. I think you mean "parameters".